# How to hide expression label in Grafana?

Tags: grafana

My Grafana panel consists of 4 queries: `A`,`B`,`C` and `D`.
All of them but `D` are hidden. They all have same label names so I suppose that grafana adds `D` prefix to avoid name collisions.

[image]

The thing is that I won't have name collisions because only last query is visible. Can I somehow hide this `D` prefix?

These are my last query settings:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can set the "Display name" property on the panel options, assuming what is show is in a label like `instance`:

[image: shows display name in right side toolbar which has the panel options]

Answer (score 0):

you can transform using the rename my regex option.

[image]